# Are artificial satellites impacted primarily by natural or artificial particles?

Tags: debris, meteoroid

Are functional artificial satellites/space stations/spacecraft/probes impacted primarily by natural or artificial particles/debris? Lets go by something comparable like impact frequency per mass/diameter range.